# How to access specific anchor tag element enclosed in <ul></ul> in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, jquery-click-event

I've a following HTML code snippet:

```
<ul id="popover-content" class="list-group" style="display: none">
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-edit-event" href="ajax_edit_event.php?op=view&event_id={$eventDetails.event_details.event_id}" class="list-group-item" data-dismiss="modal">Edit Event</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Invite Members</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Delete Event</a>
</ul>
```

Now I want to access the first anchor tag element in jQuery. I want to write some logic when that anchor tag is clicked. Please note that I can't assign an Id to any of these anchor tags. If I assign the Id the intended other jQuery functionality doesn't work. So I don't want to make any change in above HTML code. Please suggest me a jQuery way solution for click event of first hyperlink. Better if you provide solution for all the three anchor tags.

Thanks.

Thanks

Comment: That is invalid html .... `<a>` can't be child of `<ul>`. Using selectors on invalid markup can produce unpredictable results. Also please show what you have tried

Comment: What have  you tried? This task is way too easy...

Comment: @nicael: I tried to achieve it by using id for the first anchor tag. But the other functionality stops working.

Comment: @charlietfl: Actually it's Bootstrap framework I'm using for UI design that's why it looks like it only.

Comment: bootstrap is a css framework. Your html still needs to be valid and a css framework doesn't change that. Change outer to `<div>` to make it valid or wrap `<a>` in `<li>`

Comment: So you haven't tried anything to solve your problem, which is: to get the first `<a>` of `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "ul a:first-child" ).click(function(){
 //Your code goes here
});
```

You should really do some more research next time on your own! That's a very very simple task ;).

Answer (score 0):

Check: https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

So you can do

```
$( "#popover-content a:eq(1)" ).on('click', function(){
 //first
});

$( "#popover-content a:eq(2)" ).on('click', function(){
 //second
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set a `onclick` handler on all the `a` progeny of `"#popover-content`:

```
$("#popover-content a" ).on('click',
    function () { 
        if ($(this).index() == 0) {
            //first
        } elseif ($(this).index() == 1) {
            //second
        } elseif ($(this).index() == 2) {
            //third
        }
    }
);
```